# arch install: bootctl hanging: firmware bug Page fault caused by firmware at PA

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, firmware

Installing arch to a single boot using systemd-boot.

```
 bootctl --path=/boot install
 Copied "/usr/lib/systemd/boot/efi/systemd-bootx64.efi to /boot/EFI/systemd-bootx64.efi"
 Random seed file /boot/loader/random-seed successfully written (512 bytes)
```

The process hangs at this point and the only fix is to Ctl-Z

Usually if it completes we have *img files in /boot.

```
/boot/initramfs-linux.img 
/boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img 
/boot/vmlinuz-linux
```

These are not copied. I could try copying them in manually but I can't `find` them using `find` or `pacman -F`.

The journal shows

```
 Firmware bug Page fault caused by firmware at PA....
```

I have used this same iso to install arch to a VM and encountered no issues so I'm assuming this is something to do with the target machine.

What could it be?

I have checked the target disk /dev/sda for bad blocks but not sure what else to look at.